# iOS NSDateFormatter returns wrong date from string

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using the same, unmodified `NSDateFormatter` to encode and decode dates from strings. Encoding date to string works fine, but getting it back is oddly not working well. It's not even a matter of time zones, as most dates are *several months* off. I have:

```
NSDateFormatter *_calibrationDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_calibrationDateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMM d, YYYY"];
NSString *text = @"Thursday Dec 6, 2018";
NSLog(@"%@\n%@", text, [_calibrationDateFormat dateFromString:text]);
```

The output:

```
Monday Aug 12, 2013
2012-12-31 05:00:00 +0000
```

A few more tries with other dates:

```
Friday Apr 12, 2013
2013-01-04 05:00:00 +0000

Saturday Oct 26, 2013
2013-01-05 05:00:00 +0000

Thursday Sep 10, 2015
2015-01-01 05:00:00 +0000

Thursday Jan 5, 2017
2017-01-05 05:00:00 +0000
```

I'm really at a loss as to the logic by which it decodes those dates. I tried different formats too, such as removing the day of the week, or using full month name instead of 3-letter abbreviation, but the results are similarly confusing. Note that for my tests I was using a UIDatePicker and encoding the resulting date with the same date formatter, so as to avoid any human error in formatting the date. Is there any reliable way to get the date object from a human readable date string like that?

Comment: I don't really care for time zones, most of the dates are way off. It seems to have an affinity to picking dates in January, instead of the one I actually select. Jan 5 remains Jan 5, but September, October, etc - become some other dates in January. Really odd.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`. The uppercase variant is for "week of year" based calendars (see [the UTS spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more), which isn't actually the same as getting the literal calendar year in many (most?) situations. Using `@"EEEE MMM d, yyyy"` as the date formatter may fix this for you.

Comment: Good catch, turns out I was using this unintentionally throughout my project.